# c++ structures and constructures

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, structure

ok so i nee help with this constructures

```
struct balls {
         balls()
         {
                SetTimer(hWnd, balls.BALL_ID, 1, null);
         }
    int Ex;
    int Ey;
    UINT_PTR BALL_ID;
};
```

well when i set the timer im having trouble with balls.BALL_ID. the compiler thinks that balls is structure like balls something.   well i want ball to have the value of the structure. like this

```
         balls()
         {
                SetTimer(hWnd, balls.BALL_ID, 1, null);
         }
    int Ex;
    int Ey;
    UINT_PTR BALL_ID;
};
balls something;
```

now it creates the structure with something.BALL_ID instead of balls.BALL_ID.
in balls() that wat it do it changes balls() to something().
any idea how to change the balls.BALL_ID to stuctureName.BALL_ID?

Comment: These are called "constructors" not "constructures".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BALL_ID` is a member of the `balls` struct so when you want to use it within a member function you don't need to prefix it with the name of an instance.
So just initialize `BALL_ID` then use it:

```
struct balls {
         balls( UINT_PTR id ) : BALL_ID( id ), Ex( 0 ), Ey( 0 )
         {
                SetTimer(hWnd, BALL_ID, 1, NULL);
         }
    int Ex;
    int Ey;
    UINT_PTR BALL_ID;
};

balls something( IDT_TIMER1 );
```

Comment: Note that hWnd must be accessible too.

Comment: @Anthony: that's exactly right, I've slightly assumed hWnd to be a global variable... (and just realized I wrote `null` instead of `NULL`).

Answer (score 0):

balls.BALL_ID requries 'ball' to be an object expression. Here 'balls' is a class. So the code is ill-formed.

$5.2.5/2 states- "For the first option (dot) the type of the first expression (the object expression) shall be “class object” (of a complete type)."

So, your call could be

```
SetTimer(hWnd, BALL_ID, 1, null);
```

Also, please initialize all the class members in the constructor before using them.